# How to get a Spring XD Module metadata from within the module itself

Tags: spring, spring-xd

I created a Spring XD module that needs to have access to its [ModuleMedatada](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/spring-xd-dirt/src/main/java/org/springframework/xd/dirt/module/store/ModuleMetadata.java).

I can get metadata through [ZooKeeperModuleMetadataRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/spring-xd-dirt/src/main/java/org/springframework/xd/dirt/module/store/ZooKeeperModuleMetadataRepository.java) but I'm yet to find out how can I uniquely identify my running module.

Given the sample module:

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class DummyAugmenter {

    @Transformer(inputChannel = "input", outputChannel = "output")
    public Message<?> augmentMessage(Message<?> originalMessage) throws IOException {
        // Get module metada
        System.out.println("I am associated with stream " + 
                                metadata.getUnitName() + 
                                " and my instance number is " + 
                                metadata.getId().getIndex());
        // Some logic 
        return newMsg;
    }
}
```

In the [plugin documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/#XD-Spring-Application-Contexts) it is emphasised that a module has its own context, however it is unclear how to get that context (if possible) and what information it holds.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the module metadata information is provided through the properties sources. You can get them through:

```
    @Value("${xd.module.name}")
    private String moduleName;

    @Value("${xd.module.sequence}")
    private String moduleIdx;

    @Value("${xd.container.id}")
    private String containerId;

    @Value("${xd.stream.name}")
    private String streamName;

    // ...
```

Comment: Correct, the module metadata itself is not registered as a bean; it is used to populate the environment. So you can wire in any properties from the metadata `@Value("${prefix}") String prefix;`, as well as the runtime properties `xd.*`/